# drop packet is showing in .cc file but is not included in trace file NS-2

Tags: ns2, lte

I am running a script where there is a bottleneck queue (**Queue/LTEQueue/DLAirQueue**, which has two object pointer to **DropTail** queue). Dropped packet is showing when using this queue (Checking by **printf**, let, drop packet=8000) file but is not included in trace file (.tr)**(there is no 'd').**

```
1. $ns simplex-link $eNB $UE($i) 10Mb 2ms DropTail 
2. $ns simplex-link $eNB $UE($i) 10Mb 2ms LTEQueue/DLAirQueue
```

If 1 is used, then [drop_->recv(p);] works; packets are dropped as usual also showing in trace file.
But, if 2 is used, then [Packet::free(p);] works; No drops as well as in trace file.

Can anyone help in this issue those who are using LTE model in NS 2.35?

```
/common/connector.cc

void Connector::drop(Packet* p)
{
if (drop_ != 0)
drop_->recv(p);
else
Packet::free(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

? Did you compile the new function into a new executable 'ns' ?

( No files.cc are used at "ns runtime" ).

Besides that, ns2 is a tcl/otcl application, and you will have to investigate if the new function also must be added to tcl/lib/{ [files].tcl } .... ( Changes in tcl/lib/* must also be compiled into the new 'ns'.)

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: @Kund : I create a new queue which is using droptail queue.  I recompile and make a new executable ns.when run by droptail, it shows the 'd' but it shows no 'd' when run by my queue.  Why?? I don't understand.